# Summing/Counting equal values/rows of a data frame

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a dataframe that contains a bunch of individual trip data, with a start and end station ID for each trip.

I'm trying to make a second dataframe that is all the info rearranged for each station. So for example, if there are 50 trips with start_station_id == 12 in the first dataframe, then the second dataframe under station_id 12 would have its "starts" column equal to 50

Currently I figured a `for` loop would be the best method for this, but I cant seem to crack it

```
for(i in range(station_ids)){
   stationData$starts[i] <- sum(data$start_station_id[i] == station_ids[i])
}
```

This produces the following error:

```r
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, starts, value = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,  : 
  replacement has 370 rows, data has 369
```

station_id's is a variable that contains each unique station id #, stationData$starts is where I want the number of starts stored. Data is the original data I am trying to run the for loop over.

Is there an easier way to complete this operation or am I just writing the for loop wrong? Any tips would be super helpful

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: hard to help without a sample of your data, but something like `ddply(data, .(station_id), summarise, <summary functions>)` could do what you want without loops

Comment: shouldn't u use `data$start_station_id == station_ids[i]` plus it would be faster to just use the `table` function =>  `table(data$start_station_id)`

Answer (score 0):

From what I have understood from your question you're trying to count the occurences of each `station_id` this can be easily achieved by the `table` function which returns a `table` object ie a named vector containing the count and `station_id` as the names.

## base `R`

```r
table(data$start_station_id)
data.frame(table(data$start_station_id)) #if you prefer the data.frame look
```

If you want to have the number of occurence merged into your old `data.frame` can inner join the two `data.frames` using the `merge` function

```r
tbl.df <-data.frame(table(data$start_station_id))
colnames(tbl.df)[1] <- "start_station_id"
data <- merge(data, tbl.df)
```

## `data.table`

```
data.table::setDT(data)
data[, `Number of rows` := .N, by = start_station_id]
```

the `:=` is a `data.table` function that creates new columns, the `.N` give the count of the rows for the current group, the `by` specifies by which column to group. this automatically adds the column `Number of rows` to the `data.table`.
for an introduction on the `data.table` package check the [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html).
this implementation is the fastest.

Answer (score 0):

The approach is feasible but you should not use a data.frame to put your fresh data in as you don't know the row counts, yet. Just use a list and convert it to data.frame in the end:

```
stationData = list("station" = unique(c(data$start_station_id, data$end_station_id)), ##  Create a list of all stations
                   "starts" = c(),

for(i in i:length(stationData$station)){
   s = stationData$station[i]
   stationData$starts[i] <- sum(data$start_station_id == s)
}
stationData = as.data.frame(stationData)
```

At the end of the for-loop the length of both columns will be identical and there will be no problem to create this data.

A much easier way, though, would be to use the `table()` function, which computes the number of starting stations automatically and was already proposed by Abdessabour Mtk.